# RenderUI - snytax problems

Tags: r

The objective is to call a .csv file.

From there the user should select a characteristic like "Total Chat Questions" which then produces a plot of the time series data e.g. number of chats per month.

I am stuck on how to get the UIrender to pass data back and forth. This is really just taken from the R example of worldphones so not my original work.

```
 UI
    # Rely on the 'WorldPhones' dataset in the datasets
    # package (which generally comes preloaded).
    library(datasets)
library(ggplot2)
library(readr)

oboler_data <- read_csv(file = "C:/Users/12083/Desktop/ref.csv")
rdate <- as.Date(oboler_data$DATE,"%m/%d/%y")
# Use a fluid Bootstrap layout
fluidPage(    

    # Give the page a title
    titlePanel("Teephones by region"),

    # Generate a row with a sidebar
    sidebarLayout(      




        # Define the sidebar with one input
        sidebarPanel(


                                        output$regionSel = renderUI(selectInput("region", "Type of Questions:",
                                                                                choices=colnames(oboler_data)))


            #selectInput("region", "Region:", 
                       # choices=colnames(WorldPhones)),

            hr()
            helpText("Data from the Library.")
       # ),

        # Create a spot for the barplot
        mainPanel(
            plotOutput("myPlot")  
        )

    #)
#)



server
# Rely on the 'WorldPhones' dataset in the datasets
# package (which generally comes preloaded).
library(datasets)
library(ggplot2)
oboler_data <- read_csv(file = "C:/Users/12083/Desktop/ref.csv")
rdate <- as.Date(oboler_data$DATE,"%m/%d/%y")
# Define a server for the Shiny app
function(input, output) {

  # Fill in the spot we created for a plot
  output$myPlot = renderPlot({


    # Render a barplot
    ggplot(data = oboler_data, aes_string(x = "date", y = input$regionSel)) +
      geom_point() +
      labs(x = "Date",
           y = "Total Transactions",
           title = "Library Data",
           subtitle = "July 2020-June 2021") 
    })

Error message
Error in parse(file, keep.source = FALSE, srcfile = src, encoding = enc) : 
  C:\Users\12083\Documents\tester/ui.R:25:58: unexpected '='
24:                                
25:                                         output$regionSel =
                                                             ^
Possible missing comma at:
32:            hr()
               ^
Possible missing comma at:
33:            helpText("Data from the Library.")
               ^
Possible missing comma at:
37:        mainPanel(
           ^
Warning: Error in sourceUTF8: Error sourcing C:\Users\12083\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpaaFXGB\file4c947a3c4d0
  [No stack trace available]
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO, Karl.

You've put severe code in the middle of your UI.  Replace

```
output$regionSel = renderUI(selectInput("region", "Type of Questions:",
                                        choices=colnames(oboler_data)))
```

```
with uiOutput("regionSel")
```

and move the original code into your server function.  That has more chance of working.

Comment: That didn't help at all. Without knowing where you are saying to put this it doesn't help.

Comment: That didn't help at all. Without knowing where you are saying to put this it doesn't help. I think the UI said worked -- or at least stepping through it there were no errors but the server side says Error in output$myPlot = renderPlot({ : object 'output' not found.

Comment: I have spent two hours on this. By now the suggested changes have introduced so many errors I will have to start over. If someone is willing to post my original code with the changes in the right place great - thank you. As it is I have to start this entire project over from scratch and see what the problem is.